# How to limit file modifications to a single branch in Git

Tags: git

I'm starting to learn Git, reading the ProGit book from time to time. I've heard that the most powerful feature of Git is the branches, so I tried to use them. I'm hacking on the KDE project, so there is a remote server and a local copy.

So here's my situation. I've coded a bugfix, but the developer responsible for that code area has gone offline without having given me a shipit, so I decided to do a different fix in the meantime. I've heard that branches can (and more importantly, should) be used for such situations. OK, I created a local branch

```
git branch bugfix
```

then switched to that branch

```
git checkout bugfix
```

ad then discovered that the files I had modified for the original fix were still modified. (Of course, I needed a clean directory to be able to push only the second bugfix without the first one.) Well, no problem, I thought, let's reset if that's what `git status` tells me to do. I did a reset and indeed got a clean dir. But hey, after I switched back to master

```
git checkout master
```

the modified files  were no longer modified there! It was a clean dir.

Now what's the point of branches? Can't have two versions of a file, modified in one branch and unmodified in another one? I know about `git stash`, but if I do that, unstashing the changes will kill the second bugfix, because IIRC stash simply replaces one file with another one, no merging is done.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it impossible to have the file modifed in one branch and unmodified in another?

Comment: Did you commit your changes in the first branch? If not, then the modifications will stay, if you checkout another branch.

Comment: I know I've written other answers about this (maybe I'll find one in a bit here) but the thing that you're missing is that your working directory has nothing to do with a branch. A branch points to a commit, and the current branch is where the next commit you'll make will go. The uncommitted modifications are uncommitted, and therefore not associated with any branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, here's what happened.  You started off with a commit A from the original developer.  You fixed some bugs and now you're in B.  There's a remote branch pointing to A called `origin/original-branch`, and there's a local branch pointing to B called `my-changes`.  I don't know what they're actually called (use `git branch -a` to list them).

```
....->  A  ->  B
        ^      ^
        |      +-- my-changes
        |
        +-- origin/original-branch
```

If you're on B and you make a branch and start making changes, you'll get this:

```
....->  A  ->  B  ->  C
        ^      ^      ^
        |      |      +-- bugfix
        |      |
        |      +-- my-changes
        |
        +-- origin/original-branch
```

This is not what you want.  You want this:

```
               +-- my-changes
               v
....->  A  ->  B
         \
           ->  C
        ^      ^
        |      +-- bugfix
        |
        +-- origin/original-branch
```

So you have to make your new branch start where the other developer's branch is.

```
git branch bugfix origin/original-branch
git checkout bugfix
```

That specifies that the new branch starts from the other developer's work.  If you do this instead:

```
git branch bugfix # not what you want
```

This will cause the `bugfix` branch to start from wherever you are right now.

Comment: Surreally awesome answer! Makes perfect sense. This is what I'm going to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit the files onto a branch in order for them to be on that branch.

In your case, you made some modifications to some files, but didn't commit them in to any branch.

What you could have done was:

1. `git checkout -b bugfix`
2. `git commit -am "Fixed some bugs"`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git checkout -b bugfixtwo`
5. At this point, your original work will be on master, your first changes will be bugfix, and you will be ready to do new work on bugfixtwo

`git checkout -b bugFix` creates and checks out a branch in one step.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "remember" a changed file on a branch, you need to commit your changes (added, removed, or modified files): git commit -a (the -a argument stands for "all changes") but you definitely need to understand git branches. [This book](http://progit.org/) is very useful.